# How to create a job using only default bash commands?

Tags: bash, unix, job-control

So, I have started studying UNIX systems about a month ago and now I have a basic question about job control

How can I create a job, that will contain several processes, using only default bash commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo | ping google.com &
```

Was fine example, because both of these processes work independently and only require pipe symbol (|) to work in sync in the background

Answer (score 0):

`jobs` are usually an interactive shell concept, as there is usually a controlling terminal involved.

A shell script is executed in a non-interactive, non-login session of shell, hence no job control by default.

You can force job control inside a script, by setting:

```
set -m
```

inside the script.

From help set:

`-m`  Job control is enabled.

Comment: Thank you, but my question was more about how to create custom job, that will include several processes without any scripts

Comment: Same here in Indian College in which I'm studying. I am also second year student but want to study bash and UNIX for entering in cyber security field as it will be easy afterwards if I know it well. So please suggest something if possible :)

Comment: http://parallels.nsu.ru/~fat/unixsvr4-new/trunk/Irtegov-OS-Unix-System-Calls.pdf if you want to use some Google Translate

Comment: do you have interest in going to cyber security field